# How to Drag and Drop between full screen apps on a Mac using a standard mouse?

Tags: macos, mouse, ui

I have a Logitech mouse. I often maximize my applications in OS X. E.g. I will have Evernote running on one Desktop and Google Chrome running on another, both in full screen mode.

Suppose I have a file in my Downloads folder. How do I attach it into Evernote using drag and drop? Or similarly, how do I attach it to an email using drag and drop. On Windows, drag and drop is made simple by the fact that you can easily resize windows. But, with OS X, since all your windows are maximized, or at least that is how I have them, how do I drag stuff from one place to another?

P.S. I have a simple USB mouse, I am not using Apple trackpad or any such fancy thing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Grab (mouse click) the item you want to drag from say the desktop or email.
2. Hit **`Command+Tab`** on the keyboard to switch through the open apps you have running (holding `Command` down continuously, and hitting `Tab` repeatedly) until you get to the app you want to drop the file on. KEEP HOLDING DOWN ON THE MOUSE BUTTON WHILE YOU DO THIS.
3. When the app you want to drag the item to is the foreground app. You should simply be able to drop (let go of the mouse button) the item you’ve been dragging, and it should be copied or attached to that app.

Comment: Yep this works.  Wish I could get all those hours of my life spent shrinking windows and moving them side to side back.  I'll add that if you want to drag it to a specific tab in the browser (to upload to Google Photos for example), you can just Command-Tab to Chrome and then hold it over that tab in the title bar.  The tab will open and you can drop it in the page.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to kenjikato's answer, here's how I prefer to do it:

1. Click <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to reveal the desktop
2. Grab the item you want to drag
3. Click <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to hide the desktop (return to whatever app was open before execution of step 1)
4. Drop the item into the app

This solution works when you have your apps maximized but **not in the full-screen** mode.